# intersection of ideals in a commutative ring vs their product 

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra

This question was inspired by [this one.](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/49259/when-is-product-of-two-ideals-equal-their-intersection) Given two ideals $A,B$ in a finitely generated commutative ring $R$. Is it possible to decide whether $A\cap B=AB$? Here $R$ is given by generators and relations, i.e. as a factor-ring of the free commutative ring over a finitely generated ideal, $A$, $B$ are given by their (finite) generating sets. I do not remember seeing this question in standard books on Groebner bases, but perhaps it is hidden there.

Comment: Well, if you can compute $A \cap B$, then computing $AB$ is quite fast, and then use standard equality testing methods. As David Speyer pointed out in the previous question, you could also compute $Tor$.

Comment: @Karl: That is all in the ring of polynomials (say, over $\mathbb Z$). In general, you have three ideals $R, A, B$ in the polynomial ring, and you need to check $(A+R)\cap (B+R)=(AB)+R$. But I guess that can also be done using Groebner bases. Right? 

Comment: Mark, yes it can be.  It's also certainly implemented in various computer algebra programs such as Macaulay.

Comment: @Karl: It is good to know. From time to time such questions arise in group theory too (say, when one studies solvable groups). 

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think this problem can in fact be handled by Gröbner basis theory in the case $A$ is a polynomial ring. Since $I\cdot J \subseteq I\cap J$ for any two ideals, one can simply compute a Gröbner basis of $I\cap J$ (which is computed as the elimination ideal $( t\cdot I+(1-t)\cdot  I ) \cap A$) and then checking whether each generator belongs to $I\cdot J$ (again using Gröbner basis algorithm).

EDIT: As Mark points out in his comment, this argument can be used to solve the problem for the general case $A=k[X]/R$ by considering the ideals $I+R$ and $J+R$ in $k[X]$.

Comment: @J.C.: It is nice. If you have three ideals $R, I, J$ in the polynomial ring, can you also compute $(I+R)\cap (J+R)$? It would be enough.  

Comment: Yes, it is possible. The union of the gröbner bases of I and R, is the  grobner basis of the union $I+R$. This shows that one can compute $I+R$ and $J+R$ and finally their intersection by the above argument. 

Comment: @J.C.: Thank you!